Scalar propagator with additional terms
Let $\phi$ be a real scalar field. Consider the following Lagrangian:
\begin{equation}
L = -\frac{1}{2}(\partial_\mu \phi)^2 + c_1 (\partial_i \partial_j \phi)(\partial_i \partial_j \phi) + c_2 (\nabla^2 \phi)^2,
\end{equation}
where $c_1,c_2$ are some general coefficients. Is it possible to define the scalar propagator in this setting or only if $c_1 = c_2$?

Would the $c_{1,2}$ terms just contribute to corrections of the scalar propagator at some cutoff? For example, I can rescale $c_{1,2}\rightarrow c_{1,2}/\Lambda$ (assuming they are controlled by the same scale (not always the case)), and then Fourier transform to find the following matrix to invert (via $\partial_\mu\rightarrow ik_\mu$) $L = -\frac{1}{2}\phi( k^2 + \frac{2c_1}{\Lambda}(k\cdot k)^2 + \frac{2c_2}{\Lambda}(k\cdot k)^2)\phi$. We can then invert to find the "corrected" scalar propagator that's valid up to $\Lambda$.
